# Retrieving data from sql server and adding it to arraylist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from the sql server and store it in an arraylist using vb.net but it is taking only one value and exiting while statement. I want to skip first 3 columns of the sql server table and start reading from 4th column.

```
    Dim arr10 As New ArrayList
    Dim i3 As Integer
    i3 = 3
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source='" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName + "'; Initial Catalog=hrmdb; Integrated Security=True"
    con.Open()
    Dim q1 As String = "SELECT * from empsal where emplycode='" + s2.ToString + "'"
    Dim cm1 = New SqlCommand(q1, con)
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader = cm1.ExecuteReader()
    While dr1.Read()
        arr10.Add(dr1(i3).ToString)
        i3 = i3 + 1
    End While
    dr1.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation. Otherwise you're open for sql-injection.

Comment: if you're not interested in the first 3 columns, then don't return them. Instead of `select *` just use `select col4, col5, col6...`. You should always only return the data you need instead of using `select *`. Also, what Tim says!

Comment: Also... what if your column order changes in the future and an extra column is added to or deleted from the first 3 columns? This will stop  working. It's not the best approach to rely on the column index.

Comment: User does not have access to first three columns so no worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While dr1.Read()
    For i As Integer = 3 to CType(dr1, IDataRecord).FieldCount - 1
        arr10.Add(dr1(i).ToString)
    Next
End While
```